# Is it possible to get all set view variables in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

If I have a view and want to see all the set variables for the particular view, how would I do it?

Comment: are u using the default view engine? smarty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables assigned to a `Zend_View` object simply become public properties of the view object.

Here are a couple of ways to get all variables set in a particular view object.

**From within a view script:**

```
$viewVars = array();

foreach($this as $name => $value) {
    if (substr($name, 0, 1) == '_') continue; // protected or private

    $viewVars[$name] = $value;
}

// $viewVars now contains all view script variables
```

**From a `Zend_View` object in a controller:**

```
$this->view->foo = 'test';
$this->view->bar = '1234';

$viewVars = get_object_vars($this->view);
// $viewVars now contains all public properties (view variables)
```

The last example would work just as well for a view object created manually using `$view = new Zend_View();`

Answer (score 7):

There's a more elegant way: `$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables();`

For a nested viewModel: `$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getChildren()[0]->getVariables();`

Comment: Note that `$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables()` returns an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->view->getVars()
```

or from inside the view

```
$this->getVars()
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code works / how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a need to load a partial view from within another view.  This was very easy, actually.  Instead of worrying about getting the variables to pass through from a parent view to a child, simply pass the parent view object.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('my-view.phtml', $this); ?>
```

Comment: Passing `$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables()` as shown above is cleaner for inside a view script using the partial helper, have run into conflicts using passing just `$this`.